# Binary search tree change insert method return type

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I wrote an insert method for a binary search tree that is `void`. I have to change that method so that it returns a `boolean` but I am confused because my helper method for insert returns a `Node`.

Is there a way to write some other helper method that will return a `boolean`? If not, how would I go about changing my method to return a `boolean`?

This is my method:

```
public void insert(E s) 
{
    root = insert(s, root);
    root.setParent(findParent(root.getData()));
} 

private Node<E> insert(E s, Node<E> T)
{
    //easiest case, empty tree, create new tree
    if(T == null)
    {
        T = new Node<E>(s);
    }
    //s is greater than T, insert on right subtree
    else if(s.compareTo(T.getData()) > 0)
    {
        T.setRight(insert(s, T.getRight()));
    }
    //s is less than T, insert on left subtree
    else if (s.compareTo(T.getData()) < 0)
    {
        T.setLeft(insert(s,T.getLeft()));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Item already present.");

    }
    return T;
}//Close insert
```

Comment: use exceptions... Or return null in your second method as result of unsuccessful insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're supposed to return `true` if the insert is successful and `false` otherwise? Change your first `insert` function to look like this:

```
public boolean insert(E s) 
{
    try {
        root = insert(s, root);
        root.setParent(findParent(root.getData()));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And change your helper function so that if the item is already present, it throws an Exception (for the main insert function to catch and trigger the `false` return).

```
private Node<E> insert(E s, Node<E> T) throws Exception {
    ...
    else {
        System.out.println("Item already present.");
        throw new Exception("Item already present.");
    }
    return T;
}
```

**Or** (as Tutankhamen suggests) return `null` from the helper method in the case of an unsuccessful insertion, so you have:

```
public boolean insert(E s) 
{
    root = insert(s, root);
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }
    root.setParent(findParent(root.getData()));
    return true;
}

private Node<E> insert(E s, Node<E> T) {
    ...
    else {
        System.out.println("Item already present.");
        return null;
    }
    return T;
}
```

Comment: i think it's easier to return null :)